# Javascript Wrapping Contents of Brackets in quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to wrap the contents of some brackets in quotes. I have `test(ab)` as an input (in a string)
and I want the output to be `test('ab')`, with the addition of the quotes around the `ab`.

I have looked at several answers to similar questions, but cannot get any to wrap the string correctly,

```
input = input.replace(/\([^\)]*?\)/g, "'$&'");
```

Wraps the input like so `test'(ab)'`

Demo in action: http://jsfiddle.net/adminb/upczrogn/

Does anyone have any ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\(([^)]+)\)
```

Try this.Replace by `('$1')`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/23

```
var re = /\(([^)]+)\)/gm;
var str = 'test(ab)';
var subst = '(\'$1\')';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Comment: This works and was quick. Thanks. (Also found out about regex101, interesting site.)

Answer (score 0):

```
.replace(/\((.+)\)*?\)/g, "('$1')");
```

Here you go!

(could definitely be improved, but it works!)